# Applaud (Phonegap) application not acknowledging cookies

Tags: cookies, cordova, applaud

I have an app built for Android (and hopefully soon iPhone) using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)'s web interface [AppLaud](http://applaudcloud.com/).

It's working almost perfectly, except that it does not seem to be acknowledging cookie data.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449736/storing-and-sending-of-http-cookies-not-working-in-phonegap-app), which addresses pretty much the same issue, except the answer is targeted for the [Phonegap Eclipse plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android). Even if I understood the answer (which I don't fully), I don't see how I would apply it in the **AppLaud** interface.

How do I get an AppLaud built app to store and receive cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the methods exposed here: [Android: How to store cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082799/android-how-to-store-cookies) by adding them to the onCreate or init methods of the App.java class of the PhoneGap project.

You should have a file called app.java in your PhoneGap project, probably with this contents or similar:

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Modify it to look like this to test the CodeSyncManager example:

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't do any Java programming at all (otherwise I'd skip Phonegap and just develop a native Android app), and so this is a little beyond me. If there are instructions that can be utilized by a non-Java-programmer, then that would be fantastic.

Comment: Well, to make this work it seems that you need to add native code both for Android and iOS. I will try to comeup with and example so you can easily test.

Comment: Thank you for providing code and clear instructions. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any App.java class anywere in the files I have access to within the AppLaud interface.

Comment: The App.java file is at the lowest layer of the src directory in an AppLaud project

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. I awarded you the bounty, as you were providing concrete help. However, in the end the issue was mooted by using local storage, a solution I got to by asking in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10747280/184108).

Comment: @PaulBeusterien: Oh, I get it now. I thought there was literally a file called "app.java", but you guys mean a file called "(name of my app).java". Now I see it.